# css - display: table-cell and fixed width

Tags: html, css

I have some `divs` with `display: table-cell` style and I would like to set fixed width on the `divs` and to truncate the text inside if it doesn't fit.

**HTML**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="cell" style="width:100px;">Should not fit in 100px</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
 .row {
     display: table-row;
}

.cell {
    display: table-cell;
    border: solid 1px #DADADA;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

[FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/lgal/byx2d460/)

Is it possible?

Comment: You can't set a fixed width on table-cell elements

Comment: @Guy I think you are the only one seeing actuall cells here.. since Levi is using div's

Comment: @Azrael a div can be a table-cell element by changing its display property to `display: table-cell;`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can set `max-width` instead:

```
<div class="cell" style="max-width:100px;">Should not fit in 100px</div>
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/byx2d460/1/)

Comment: any way we can set the width in percentages?