# Strange "nth-of-type" behavior

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here is just another approach for table-style layout using <ul> and <li>.

Each <ul> is a row, and each <li> is a cell.
The 1st <ul> is a header row, so it has a special styling which works fine.
For the widths of each columns, I would like to add "individual styling", using the advantage of "nth-of-child" instead of class.

Here is the HTML&CSS content:

```js
var D, T, R;

function I() {
  D = document.getElementById("D");
  R = document.getElementById("R");

  // To keep 1st row always visible.
  D.onscroll = function() {
    R.style.top = D.scrollTop + "px";
  }

  // This is just arbitrary content
  var k = ["Va", "Vb"];
  for (var i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
    var e = document.createElement("ul");
    D.appendChild(e);
    for (var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
      var d = document.createElement("li");
      e.appendChild(d);
      d.innerHTML = (!j) ? i : k[j - 1];
    }
  }
}
I();
```

```css
#D {
  position: absolute;
  left: 250px;
  right: 50px;
  top: 50px;
  bottom: 50px;
  background-color: #ff8;
  overflow: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul li {
  display: table-cell;
}

ul:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #eee;
}

ul:nth-child(even) {
  background: #ddd;
}

ul:first-of-type {
  background: #888;
  color: #00f;
  position: relative;
}

#D ul li:nth-of-type(1) {
  width: 100px;
}

#D ul li:nth-of-type(2) {
  width: 200px;
}

#D ul li:nth-of-type(3) {
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div id="D">
  <ul id="R">
    <!-- 假行 Fake row -->
    <li>请不要说谎：</li>
    <li>这个不是表格 (table)！！！<br>
      <div style="position:relative; left:0; right:0;"><select style="width:100%;">
        <option>全部</option>
       </select></div>
    </li>
    <li>这是2D目录(ul和li)！！！</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

NOTE: This is a test content and not production part, so please don't comment on the <style> to be in the <div> element or why I am not just using `<table>`.
NOTE: The use of "nth-of-type(1)" and not "first-of-type" here is just for convenience.

THE RESULT: columns 2 and 3 works perfect. Column one remains "auto" - not 100px wide

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: What you had wrong was (before your edit): comment code in `style` tag. `<style>         <!-- 内部宽度 Inner widths -->
    #D ul li:nth-of-type(1){ width:100px; }
    ........`

Comment: [Are you sure it's not working?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D7cgL.png)

Comment: [See this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25888822/css-display-table-cell-and-fixed-width)

Comment: @i--: I think the edit fixed it.

Comment: Yes, this issue been solved, though the widths end-up not as per defined, if the total width of the "#D" is smaller than 600px. (shrink the window). Anyway I don't understand why wrong way of comments in CSS affected only the first rule - is it took the comment as class name...? I know I suppose to use /**/ to comment in CSS, I by mistake thought <style> tag to be part of HTML, and was sure CSS will ignore it.